# User not authorized to act as service account

Tags: service-accounts, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm a newbie on GCP and going to transfer tables from azure blob storage to the cloud bucket.
I follow the instructions [here](https://medium.com/@amald.nav/copying-data-from-azure-to-gcp-9d74eaff5389) (use data fusion).

When I finished deploying the pipeline and was going to run it, I got an error and in the advanced log is said

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: User not authorized to act as service account '####-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'.
```

I looked through several documentation and also tried looking for answers on stackoverflow but none of them work for me.

How should I grant access to a service account and which service account should I be attached to?

Now on my IAM/service accounts console, I am also assigned as Service Account User, and I only have two default services one for compute engine and one for app engine.

Really don't know what to do. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: btw I'm also the ower

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the [Service Account User role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role). [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-grant-role-sa-console) is an example of that. This should be perofrmed to the current user/service account you are using to run the job. As exemplified below:

1. Go to the IAM & Admin Console
2. Click on IAM
3. Select the member you are using to run your job
4. Click on the pen icon in the right side of the member's info
5. Add the Service Account user role

In general terms, the error is related to the lack of Service Account user role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) associate to the user/service account used to run the job.

Keep in mind that service accounts are used to make authorised API calls, through the service account itself or through delegated users within it. Moreover, about impersonation service accounts, an user with particular permissions can act as another service account with the necessary permission to execute a specific job.

Comment: I would like to add that the most probable service account used to run the data fusion job is the default data fusion service account which should be `service-####@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com` where #### stands for your project number. Follow @JoX steps and add the Service Account User role to this service account and try again. Let us know if it does work or not. This is well documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222520/dataproc-operation-failure-invalid-argument-user-not-authorized-to-act-as-serv) past post.